# how to clean a tweet using regex without removing punctuations and hasthag?

Tags: regex, twitter

i want to use tweets for sentiment analysis. i need to get rid of the usernames and links and attached files but not the punctuations and hashtags as i'm taking out the polarity on sentence level. i'm using the following statement

```
text=' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", text).split())
```

but the above statement removes everything and returns just words.

input:

```
RT @UniversalIND: #F8 is now playing in the theaters near you! So hurry and book your tickets https://www.abcabcabc.com :D ;)
```

output:

```
RT F8 is now playing in the theaters near you So hurry and book your tickets
```

required output:

```
RT #F8 is now playing in the theaters near you! So hurry and book your tickets
```

can someone suggest any way?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
text = 'RT @UniversalIND: #F8 is now playing in the theaters near you! So hurry and book your tickets https://www.abcabcabc.com'
text = re.sub(r'@\S+|https?://\S+', '', text)

print(text)
```

The output:

```
RT  #F8 is now playing in the theaters near you! So hurry and book your tickets
```

---

`@\S+|https?://\S+` - matches either a substring which starts with `@` and  contains non-whitespace characters `\S+` OR a link(url) which starts with `http(s)://`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, It doesn't. Look at `F8` substring, it has no preceding `#`, while it should be there. Also, `you` should be `you!`

Comment: Sorry, the OP said nothing came back and I saw something hence my comment.

Comment: @RIYACHAUDHARYB15EE029, see my explanation

Comment: so you mean it covers emoticons too?

Comment: @RIYACHAUDHARYB15EE029, you have wrote *to get rid of the usernames and links* and posted the expected output. That was what I had been relying on

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes i'm sorry for my miscommunication. Can you include getting rid of emoticons too?

Comment: @RIYACHAUDHARYB15EE029, you should specify what are "emoticons" in your input and update the expected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest edited. you may look at the changed input now.